# Read a file from a different server

Tags: php, ip

**Reason:**
I am a webmaster of 7 sites, and to manage unwanted comments on a contact form I block the IP of bad commentators. Each time i get a new bad IP I have to edit each contact form on all 7 servers, which is very time consuming. What i would like is for the IP addresses to be put in 1 file on my server and just read in my all the other sites.

**Current Code:** (I have shortened the IP array)

```
<?php
$deny = array("91.200.14.59", "91.207.7.141");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("location: index.php?page=error404");
   exit();
} ?>
```

**Answer Required:**
How do i get the above code to read the IP file (array) from another server? 
An example of the code would truly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are going about this wrong, you should have a text file of blocked IP's. You don't want to be including remote PHP scripts for execution.

Comment: Why wouldn't you put them in a database?

Comment: Why wouldn't you set up a decent deploy mechanism that can push the updated blacklist automatically to all your servers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be going about this the other way around: keep the list up to date locally (in a version control repository no less), and push the changes using a deploy tool. For instance, [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) is a neat little tool. Example configuration:

```
---
- hosts: comment-forms
  tasks:
      - name: Ensure blacklist is up to date
        copy: src=blacklist.txt
              dest=/var/www/conf/blacklist.txt
              owner=www-data
              group=www-data
              mode=440
```

Then deploy whenever you update the list:

```
$ ansible-playbook blacklist.yml
```

It's that easy, once you've set it up. And it means you don't need to make costly remote requests from your servers all the time.

Answer (score 0):

here what you can do:

1. Create one blocked IP  file on one of your servers.

   - e.g filename = blockip.txt
   - content of blockip.txt:
     91.200.14.59,91.207.7.141..
2. Make sure the file is accessible via http protocol.
          e.g: http://www.example.com/blockip.txt
3. On your application server, create a function which will read blockip.txt file and compare with the remote ip .
   e.g:

   ```
   <?php function check_spam_user($remote_ip){
           $x = file_get_content('http://www.example.com/blockip.txt');
           if(strpos($x,$remote_ip) === FALSE){
                //real user
           }
           else {
             //spammers
           }
        } ?>
   ```

   You can use any logic for reading file and comparing ip address.

With this every time you got new IP address you need to update just blockip.txt file, rest all will be taken care by function check_span_user().

Comment: hi Ramesh, i still just can't seem to get it to work, i need some more help

Comment: Hi @WarrenM.Walker you need to create a single file which will contain all blocked ip list on anyone of your server. After that you need to modify your code on all the 7 servers, so that you can read that file remotely and check the user ip address is already present in that file or not.